# "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" fetching referrer parameters on Broadcast has up to 15 seconds delays on some devices

Tags: android, google-play, install-referrer

My server creates a link that redirects and passes parameters to google play store;

The sms I receive by my Server;
https://goo.gl/{UNIQUE_ID}

when I click, I actually click on this this url below;
http://www.mycompany.com/env=dev&token=123&id=456

The link above directs me to google play store to my app included parameters;
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.app&referrer=123,456

Here is the question;(First time installation)
When I install the app opened with the link above, I want to pass those "token", "id" parameters to my app in first time then I will skip login. These parameters creating by server because they are also unique to user.

I have setup the "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" and I am able to receive parameters as expected but not consistent on every devices and could face with big delays.

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".GooglePlayReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My GooglePlayReceiver Broadcastreceiver is;

```
public class GooglePlayReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context mContext;
String purchaseId = null;

public GooglePlayReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        mContext = context;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String verificationCode = null;
        String phoneNumber = null;
        if (extras != null) {
            String code = extras.getString("referrer");
            String[] strArr = code != null ? code.split(",") : new String[0];
            token = strArr[0];
            id = strArr[1];
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}}
```

This flow has big delays on some devices. For ex, Google Pixel 2 fetches the parameters immediately without delay, Samsung Galaxy S7 has 5-10 seconds delay.

How to solve this?

Comment: try increasing the priority in the receiver.. and update if it works.. `<receiver android:priority = 1245658284>`like this

Comment: I did not really work. @SantanuSur

Answer (score 0):

Because the `INSTALL_REFERRER` is sent as a broadcast ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html)) it uses the publish subscribe model. There is no guarantee about timing.

Because of this you shouldn't design your app startup flow to rely on receiving the broadcast within a certain length of time. Android is open source, and changes made my different phone manufacturers will cause different promptness in the delivery of broadcasts.

I'd have a different design for your app:

- take the user always to the normal setup flow
- if the broadcast arrives later, allow the user to skip login

Comment: All they are good options but is there any other guaranteed way to receive this google play store referrer parameters into app before trigger the app for the first time?