# What is the way to receive google play store referrer parameters inside the app for first time usage?

Tags: android, google-play

My server creates a link that redirects and passes parameters to google play store;

The sms I receive by my Server; https://goo.gl/{UNIQUE_ID}

when I click, I actually click on this this url below; http://www.mycompany.com/env=dev&token=123&id=456

The link above directs me to google play store to my app included parameters; https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.app&referrer=123,456

Here is the question;(First time installation) When I install the app opened with the link above, I want to pass those "token", "id" parameters to my app in first time then I will skip login. These parameters creating by server because they are also unique to user.

Comment: Try to use a metadata activity to receive it with such myapp://open/token=123. Else, request read SMS messages for user and parse the URL you did sent.

Comment: Can you explain more the first way you defined? 
Do you mean to use deep linking? Deep link is not working before app is triggered the first time. @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: Yes, it probably will make the user click again. But i'm interested in a working solution with the first approach.

Comment: Can you give more details about your first approach? @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: Check for metadata, the user will need to click again anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["com.android.vending.INSTALL\_REFERRER" fetching referrer parameters on Broadcast has up to 15 seconds delays on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833318/com-android-vending-install-referrer-fetching-referrer-parameters-on-broadcast)